# How to fix "Undefined variable: gambar (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\apmt\resources\views\upload.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

[image]I can't understand why the variable is undefined for `gambar` at `foreach`. I'm also new to PHP Laravel 5.8.

(upload.blade.php)

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="1%">File</th>
            <th>Keterangan</th>
            <th width="1%">OPSI</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach ($gambar as $g)`here is the undefined variable`
          <tr>
              <td><img width="150px" src="{{ url('/data_file/'.$g->file) }}"></td>
              <td>{{$g->keterangan}}</td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="/upload/hapus/{{ $g->id }}">HAPUS</a></td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

UploadController.php

```php
    public function upload(){
        $gambar = Gambar::get();
        return view('upload',['gambar' => $gambar]);
    }   

    public function proses_upload(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'keterangan' => 'required',
        ]);

        // menyimpan data file yang diupload ke variabel $file
        $file = $request->file('file');

        $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

                // isi dengan nama folder tempat kemana file diupload
        $tujuan_upload = 'data_file';
        $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

        Gambar::create([
            'file' => $nama_file,
            'keterangan' => $request->keterangan,
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I expect that it will show an image from my file (`data_file`).The picture I upload all are just working fine. Just cannot show up in table.

Comment: Kindly show the code instead of images

Comment: show your contoller code.

Comment: Show a controller code where you define `$gambar` variable and pass a given view.

Comment: Show controller code plz.

Comment: Can you name the route with some name and instead of `redirect()->back()` use `redirect()->route('named-route')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed passing the `gambar` in the `proses_upload` function and I guess you are inserting the image in the `upload.blade.php`

```
public function proses_upload(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    'keterangan' => 'required',
]);

// menyimpan data file yang diupload ke variabel $file
$file = $request->file('file');

$nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        // isi dengan nama folder tempat kemana file diupload
$tujuan_upload = 'data_file';
$file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

Gambar::create([
    'file' => $nama_file,
    'keterangan' => $request->keterangan,
]);
$gamber = Gambar::get();
return view('upload',['gambar' => $gambar]);

}
```

Comment: but the code's are working perfectly on different laptop. On my laptop only its says undefined variable. i just cant understand why .....

Comment: On different laptop mean?

Comment: @balamurugana That could mean you've got different PHP error reporting settings on the two devices.

Comment: @ZainFarooq it means , running the code's on another laptop or pc is working well, just my laptop only making an error.

Answer (score 0):

kindly please edit your post and put your controller code in the question.
but in my opinion. the $gambar not passed correctly in your controller.
the step might help :

1. check in your controller, is $gambar has been passed correctly to your view.
2. in laravel. you can use `compact` or `with()` method for passing the variables.
   the example in controller:

   ```
   $gambar = 'path/to/file/gambar.png'
   return view('index',compact('gambar')) // it will passed $gambar in index.blade
   ```

or

```
$gambar = 'path/to/file/gambar.png'
return view('index')->with('gambar',$gambar); // it's also passed $gambar in index.blade
```

Comment: `view('upload',['gambar' => $gambar])` it's also passed `$gambar` in `index.blade` which he had done already. check here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: yup but its still undefined varible

Comment: @Laravel yep that's another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function upload()
{
$gambar = Gambar::get();
return view('upload',compact('gambar'));
OR
return viw('upload')->with('gambar',$gambar);
}   

public function proses_upload(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    'keterangan' => 'required',
]);

// menyimpan data file yang diupload ke variabel $file
$file = $request->file('file');

$nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        // isi dengan nama folder tempat kemana file diupload
$tujuan_upload = 'data_file';
$file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

Gambar::create([
    'file' => $nama_file,
    'keterangan' => $request->keterangan,
]);

return redirect()->route('upload-view');
}
```

In `web.php`

```
  Route::get('upload',UploadController@upload)->name('upload-view');
```

In your view

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="1%">File</th>
                    <th>Keterangan</th>
                    <th width="1%">OPSI</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach($gambar as $g)
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="150px" src="{{ url('/data_file/'.$g->file) }}"></td>
                    <td>{{$g->keterangan}}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="/upload/hapus/{{ $g->id }}">HAPUS</a></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: its still undefined variable..i already have put the routes in web.php
Route::get('/upload', 'UploadController@upload');
Route::post('/upload/proses','UploadController@proses_upload');

Answer (score -1):

Please do this;

```
$gambar = Gambar::all();
return view('upload',compact('gambar'));
```

First return the variable in your controller, to check what values it returns, just like I did below, if it returns then use:

```
$gambar = Gambar::all();
return $gambar;
```

Comment: `return view('upload',['gambar' => $gambar]);` and `return view('upload',compact('gambar'));` do the same thing.